# "Application Error" deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Can't seem to figure this one out and have tried a number of solutions I've found here.

My app runs locally fine, but throws an Application Error when I deploy to Heroku.

```
2013-08-29T02:26:16.045405+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
2013-08-29T02:26:17.753833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-29T02:26:21.377211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 39412 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-29T02:26:22.781105+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or     directory
2013-08-29T02:26:24.414525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-29T02:26:24.430021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It may be worth noting that I have a Procfile with this in it:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heroku chokes recognizing windows ruby environment executables.

bin/bundle bin/rake bin/rails all contain the line `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe`

Change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Then you should be able to deploy